# Issues when building APK in Unity 2021.3.25f1

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, apk, game-development

Issues when building APK in Unity 2021.3.25f1

I get a few errors when I attempt to build my game to an APK.

Here is the errors:

Configure project :launcher

````
WARN: /home/myname/Monkey Jump (No such file or directory): /home/myname/Monkey Jump```

```CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/home/myname/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.25f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/home/myname/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.25f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"```

```Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 7 seconds (6811 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)```

```UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)```



I am very new to game dev and I am only following tutorials (yes I know...)

If you guys could help me that would be absolutely awesome. Thank you!

I tried following a couple guides online. All of them are outdated.
````

Comment: Dont have spaces in the file names by the looks of it

Comment: @AzureSkyed, Welcome to SO!  Your questions will be more readable if you put code, error messages, etc. in their proper format.  Use triple backticks ``` above and below the text to do this.

Comment: @BugFinder Which files? Does this also include materials/FBX files?

Comment: arguably all of them. But look at the error. It cant find "/home/myname/monkey jump". It seems pretty clear it doesnt like the folder

Comment: @BugFinder Is there ANY way I can do it faster? Because there is aboslutley NO WAY I am going around manually renaming all the files.

Comment: Well start by changing the folder name. Then if it whines about files ......... you have little choice

Comment: @BugFinder THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been trying to fix this issue for 2 weeks. Thank you so much dude!

Comment: Weeks? All you had to do was follow the hint in the error :P